# How to turn gvfs and other user services off while temporarily not using graphical.target?

Tags: systemd, runlevel

If I use a desktop installation of Ubuntu 20.04 (for example the standard Hyper-V image promoted by Windows) I can easily turn the graphical components off, by switching the default boot target from graphical to multi-user, with the `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`. This avoids running the display manager, the xserver and some other stuff.

However I have still the problem that some user-slice services (lots of gvfs, but also dbus, tracker-miner-fs and pulse audio) are still started.

I could remove some of them them from the /etc/systemd/user/default.targets.wants/ and socket.target.wants/ directories, however I would like to have a simple system where the default target actually determines if the system is GUI enabled or not.

Is there a "lower" target für user sessions and how to make it active? And/or can I have users which dont to this on ssh sessions? (it happens even for system [uid<1000] users)

Comment: It looks like this is something controlled by [pam_systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html), through the [systemd-logind.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html) - there's some useful background at [What does pam_systemd.so do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626710/65304). How you would go about untangling SSH logins specifically I don't know (since the /etc/pam.d/sshd appears to use the same common_auth / common_account / common_session as other logins)